# no me edita la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

tengo que entregar mi proyecto de fin de curso, y en algunos puntos me estoy atascando bastante. En este caso, cuando pulso el boton EDITAR tras rellenar los inputs, no se me actualizan los datos, creo que es por el value="">, que no estará bien escrito, pero no doy con la tecla. espero que me podaís ayudar. Gracias, os dejo el codigo:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);

$validar = $_SESSION['nombre'];

$idPartido = $_GET['idPartido'];
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "myclub");
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM partidos";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
$usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Editar partido</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/fontawesome-all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/MyCluB/css/editar_user.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="../includes/_functions.php" method="POST" class="formulario">
        <div class="contenedor">
            <h1>EDITAR PARTIDO</h1>
            <div class="input-contenedor">
                    <input type="date" id="fecha" name="fecha" class="form-control" placeholder="Fecha" value="<?php echo $usuario['fecha']; ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="input-contenedor">
                    <input type="text" name="resultado" id="resultado" placeholder="Resultado" value="<?php echo $usuario['resultado']; ?>">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="editar_partido">
                    <input type="hidden" name="idPartido" value="<?php echo $idPartido; ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="botones">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn-editar">EDITAR</button>
                    <button href="../entrenador/partidosEnt.php" class="btn-cancelar">VOLVER</button>
                </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A este código le faltan un par de detalles para que funcione:

- Siempre estarás editando el primer registro de la tabla `partidos`, porque te falta un `WHERE` que te permita seleccionar los datos del registro que quieres visualizar.
- Deberías mostrar el contenido del fichero `../includes/_functions.php` para ver qué haces exactamente con los datos que recoges en la superglobal `$_POST` y averiguar por qué no se actualizan los datos. Probablemente tengas algún error en el `UPDATE` o en cualquier de las funciones de la clase `mysqli` que debes usar. Modifica tu pregunta y continuaremos ayudándote.

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias, con eso del WHERE me funcionó